# DetachedInstanceError when creating an object and trying to return a Pydantic model as response

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Still having problem with lazy load techniques I guess. I'm using response_model to return a new Pydantic model as response when creating a new object but I get the following errors:

```
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 4 validation errors:
  {'type': 'get_attribute_error', 'loc': ('response', 'event'), 'msg': "Error extracting attribute: DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <EventProductUsage at 0x1f54e57e950> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'event' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/bhk3)", 'input': <models.EventProductUsage object at 0x000001F54E57E950>, 'ctx': {'error': "DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <EventProductUsage at 0x1f54e57e950> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'event' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/bhk3)"}, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/get_attribute_error'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'product'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <models.EventProductUsage object at 0x000001F54E57E950>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'usage_type_id'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <models.EventProductUsage object at 0x000001F54E57E950>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'usage_type'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <models.EventProductUsage object at 0x000001F54E57E950>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
```

```
@router.post('/create_usage', response_model=UsageOut)
async def create_product_usage(usageSchema: UsageIn, session = Depends(get_session)):
    async with session() as session:
        usage = EventProductUsage(
            event_id=usageSchema.event_id,
            product_id=usageSchema.product_id,
            product_usage_type_id= usageSchema.usage_type_id,
            total=usageSchema.total
        )
        session.add(usage)
        await session.commit()
        return usage
```

This is part of my schemas.py. I use as input UsageIn and return that same object after saving it with UsageOut. According to documentation, it's possible but having some errors with foreign keys.

```
class EventOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    location_id: int
    location: LocationOut
    start_date: datetime
    end_date: datetime
    is_active: bool

class ProductIn(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: str
    code: str
    filename: str
    is_active: bool

class ProductOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    description: str | None = None
    code: str
    filename: str | None = None
    is_active: bool

class UsageTypeOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    value: int
    description: str | None = None
    is_active: bool

class UsageIn(BaseModel):
    event_id: int
    product_id: int
    usage_type_id: int
    total: int

class UsageOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    event_id: int
    event: EventOut
    product_id: int
    product: ProductOut
    usage_type_id: int
    usage_type: UsageTypeOut
    total: int
```

and this is part of my models.py

```
class Event(AuditMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    location_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("location.id"))
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    description: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100))
    start_date: Mapped[Optional[datetime]] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    end_date: Mapped[Optional[datetime]] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True))
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default='t', default=True)
    location: Mapped["Location"] = relationship(back_populates="events", lazy="selectin")
    products: Mapped[List["EventProductUsage"]] = relationship(back_populates="event", lazy="selectin")

class EventProductUsage(AuditMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = "event_product_usage"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    event_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("event.id"))
    product_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("product.id"))
    product_usage_type_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("product_usage_type.id"))
    total: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, default=0)
    event: Mapped["Event"] = relationship(back_populates="products", lazy="selectin")

class ProductUsageType(AuditMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = "product_usage_type"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    value: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, default=0)
    description: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100))
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default='t', default=True)
```

Comment: @Chris yeah that's my model but its schema is UsageIn / UsageOut

Comment: You might have to call refresh on the object after adding it to the session for it to become attached, but if you're going to return an ORM object, you'll also have to configure `from_attributes` as a model config on your Pydantic models, otherwise Pydantic is unable to load the values through attribute lookup.